# Multiple counts with one query whilst also taking into account a 'count distinct'

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey I don't know if this is even possible, but I'm trying to get a list of shops with a count of distinct customers, and then trying to calculate two further columns per shop for whether this appointment was an initial or a subsequent appointment... this is as far as I have got.

```
SELECT year,
shopname,
COUNT (DISTINCT appointmentkey) custappoint,
SUM (CASE WHEN attendance = 'initial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) initialapp,
SUM (CASE WHEN attendance = 'subsequent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) subapp
   FROM shoptable
     WHERE shopType in ('local')
     GROUP BY year, shopname
     ORDER BY year, shopname
```

During an appointment various things can happen, in our database this is coded for on various rows with one appointment key. Meaning that the appointmentkey turns up multiple times for one appointment, hence the code above counts the number of rows that fulfill that criteria and gives a table like;

```
shopname | custappoint | initialapp | subapp

-------- | ----------- | ---------- | ------

 local1  |    44       |   48       | 89
```

The desired result is that sum of the initial and subsequent appointments should but equal to the number of total appointments. I was trying to add in 'distinct' to the case when counts, but don't think this it the correct route. Although I'm sure someone must have had a similar instance I can't find anything similar across the web so turning to you guys!

Thanks

Comment: try using `count(distinct case when attendance = 'initial' then appointmentkey end) initialapp,count(distinct case when attendance = 'subsequent' then appointmentkey end) subapp`

Comment: You have not explained the logic for your desired results.   For each distinct appointment, if there are some rows that are initial and some that are subsequent, how should they be counted?

Answer (score 0):

If each `appointmentkey` can only have one possible `attendance` value, then you can simply select from a derived table of distinct rows:

```
SELECT year,
shopname,
COUNT (appointmentkey) custappoint,
SUM (CASE WHEN attendance = 'initial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) initialapp,
SUM (CASE WHEN attendance = 'subsequent' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) subapp
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT year, shopname, appointmentkey, attendance
   FROM shoptable
     WHERE shopType in ('local')
     GROUP BY year, shopname
     ORDER BY year, shopname
) t
```